# Newly Created DAG Not Showing Up in UI

Tags: ubuntu, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs, airflow-webserver

I recently installed Airflow on Windows 10. I have been running it via Ubuntu. I created a new DAG python file but it is not showing up in the UI. The only DAGs that show up are the example DAGs. I tried a number of different things so far, without success.

The latest thing is that in airflow.cfg, I set the below (same folder location as the example dags in the UI):
dags_folder = /home/[user name]/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/example_dags

I put the new DAG py file into the local folder that corresponds with the above folder, but no luck.
C:\Users[local username]\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\airflow\example_dags

When I even navigate on Ubuntu to that folder, my new DAG py file doesn't even appear when I enter 'ls'. Clearly I am doing something wrong. Please help, thanks.